# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when using urlparse

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm getting this error on my model function. Here's my model:

```
def Post(models.Model):
    ...
    imageURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def video_source(self):
        print(self.imageURL) #https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghi
        t = urlparse(self.imageURL).netloc #this line fires the error
        domain = '.'.join(t.split('.')[1:])
        print(domain)
        return True
```

I'm trying to create a function for my template like so:

```
{% if instance.imageURL.video_source %}
    #something
{% else %}
    #something else
{% endif %}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: _Always_ post the full, verbatim error message.

Comment: try this, `t = urlparse(self.imageURL.encode()).netloc`

Comment: Which `urlparse` is this? The one in `urllib.parse` takes strings, and will never give you this error. And I'm pretty sure Django has just re-exported the one from the stdlib for many versions (and nowadays it's deprecated and they recommend just using the stdlib directly). If I'm right, you're either using a `urlparse` function from some other library that you need to tell us about (or just need to stop using…), or you're actually using Python 2 despite your question tags and you Python 3-style `print` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL to a byte data type.

```
url = url.encode()
```